# Turning a Google Spreadsheet into a JSON feed

Tags: json, google-sheets, jsonp, getjson, google-sheets-api

I wish to firstly turn a Google Spreadsheet into a JSON feed, there are plenty of posts online for this but none seem to work, it is fully shared and public. I think the structure of the URL may have changed that is causing this not to work.

This is the file I wish to read as JSON
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/195boU7gqGLh_q2RXgnwfFVidfEn-YXakBhC4A--lej0/edit?usp=sharing

This is what I have based on https://ctrlq.org/code/20004-google-spreadsheets-json

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/195boU7gqGLh_q2RXgnwfFVidfEn-YXakBhC4A--lej0/od6/public/basic?alt=json

Secondly, I would like this Google spreadsheet to be able to be updated from a 3rd party CSV or XML file located an another URL. Is this possible?

Comment: Looks that that the spreadsheet is not published. The json URL and the pub URL returns "We're sorry. This document is not published." Pub URL:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/195boU7gqGLh_q2RXgnwfFVidfEn-YXakBhC4A--lej0/pub

Answer (score 1):

I found another [tutorial](http://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/general/databasing-google-spreadsheets-to-json) about your problem.

Just make sure you follow the step 1 here, that in your Google Spreadsheet,click the "share" button and choose the "Anyone on the internet can find and view". Also you need to publish the entire sheet in order to this. Go to "File", "Publish to the web…" and publish the entire spreadsheet.

You can also try the solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531351/retrieve-google-spreadsheet-worksheet-json?lq=1).

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/195boU7gqGLh_q2RXgnwfFVidfEn-YXakBhC4A--lej0/private/full?alt=json
```

Another workaround is by using [Google AppScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). Here is the [tutorial](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2013/06/exporting-google-spreadsheet-as-json.html) on how to do it by using AppScript.